# Cron job don't run the php code

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I try to run a `cron job` to do a backup to my database.

The problem that the `cron job` is execute  and i receive an email that the cron job is executing but the problem is i don't have a backup file.
But if i run the page on the browser without the `cron job` i have a back up file.
Also i have a button if i click this button i receive a backup file.
That mean my code work.

Cron job file:

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");
include("includes/functions.php");
include("includes/backup.php");
?>
```

Backup Function and this function is in functions.php

```
<?php
function Export_Database($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables=false,$backup_name=false)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name); 
        $mysqli->select_db($name); 
        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        $queryTables    = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES'); 
        while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()) 
        { 
            $target_tables[] = $row[0]; 
        }   
        if($tables !== false) 
        { 
            $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables); 
        }
        foreach($target_tables as $table)
        {
            $result         =   $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);  
            $fields_amount  =   $result->field_count;  
            $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;     
            $res            =   $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table); 
            $TableMLine     =   $res->fetch_row();
            $content        = (!isset($content) ?  '' : $content) . "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0) 
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_row())  
                { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                    if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )  
                    {
                            $content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";
                    }
                    $content .= "\n(";
                    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++)  
                    { 
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) ); 
                        if (isset($row[$j]))
                        {
                            $content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; 
                        }
                        else 
                        {   
                            $content .= '""';
                        }     
                        if ($j<($fields_amount-1))
                        {
                                $content.= ',';
                        }      
                    }
                    $content .=")";
                    //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                    if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num) 
                    {   
                        $content .= ";";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $content .= ",";
                    } 
                    $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
                }
            } $content .="\n\n\n";
        }

     $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/backup"."/mybackup-".date('d-m-Y')."-".date('H:i:s').".sql","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
 exit();
    }?>
```

Backup page:

```
<?php
    $mysqlUserName      = "***";
    $mysqlPassword      = "";
    $mysqlHostName      = "****";
    $DbName             = "****";
    $backup_name        = "mybackup.sql";

     $tables = array();
$showTable = "SHOW TABLES from $DbName";
$getData = mysqli_query($conn, $showTable);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getData)) {
   $tables[] = $row;
}
    Export_Database($mysqlHostName,$mysqlUserName,$mysqlPassword,$DbName,  $tables=false, $backup_name=false );
?>
```

How can i solve this problem to run the code when the cron job is execute??!!

Comment: View cron log file /var/log/cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)?

As it says on the documentation:
4.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program

```
[cron-times] mysqldump -u <dbuser> --password <pw> [--host <host] --all-databases > /opt/mysql.bkp/`date`
```

Comment: B i use this in a cron job my backup file is saved in a backup folder i have a host on godaddy

Comment: You can pipe the output to a file of choice. Simply do `> /my/path/to/file`
You can also use the shell functions of your cron-shell to get the current date.
Have this to read about how to change the cron shell:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash#94459

Comment: B i did this usr/bin/mysqldump -u dbusername -p 'dbpass' dbname>/backup/mybackup.sql            backup is the folder name mybackup.sql is the file name how to put a datetime for this name ??!!

Comment: You can do `mysqldump [...] > /backup/$(date +%d%m%Y-%H%M%S).sql`. This will generate an file name such as in php `"backup/" . date("dmY-His") . ".sql"`. For further info about the `date` shell tool consult the man page.

Comment: B i receive this error /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: It appears that you have forgotten to close the parenthesis.

Comment: B this is the line the parenthesis is closed usr/bin/mysqldump -u dbusername -p 'dbpass' dbname>/backup/$(date +%d%m%Y-%H%M%S).sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154292/discussion-between-martin-b-and-mohamad-mohamad).